# Skewed element with background color and borders introduces artifacts

Tags: css, css-transforms

Skewing an element that has both a background color and borders introduces artifacts, where the background color bleeds under the border to create a very thin "ghost border" outside the defined border. I've tested and this happens in both Chrome and Safari.

```css
body {
  padding: 3rem;
}

div {
  height: 10rem;
  transform: skew(-30deg);
  border-left: 10px solid white;
  border-right: 10px solid white;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/53FrA/

Comment: @Sagar Fundamentally, your fix relies on using transparent instead of white borders, as [this pen demonstrates](https://codepen.io/narthur/pen/VMXqRE). My design relies on using white borders, so this isn't a viable solution for me.

Comment: Try this : https://jsfiddle.net/awmz3L0b/